# suddenly start getting error when running dxa 1.5 application from local machine "Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service"

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.5, iis-and-asp.net

suddenly i have started getting error when running dxa 1.5 application from local machine "Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service".

there is no change in discovery service url or oauth authentication key.

if i deploy the application on server. application is working fine and all web pages are loading properly.
I am using dxa 1.5, web 8.5 as cms and .net framework 4.5.2

when accessing the web application from local, following are the error messages in different log files:

1. error message shown in IE browser:
   Stack Trace:

---

```
 [InvalidServiceEndpoint: Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service]    Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV4ServiceEndpoint()
    +171    Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor() +77    Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider.get_Instance()
    +145    Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url) +195    Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url) +89    Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url)
    +797    Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() +80    Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) +320    Tmsc.Web.Site.Areas.Core.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Areas\Core\Controllers\PageController.cs:36    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +142    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
    +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
    +396    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
    +396    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
    +38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +32    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +46    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    +38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    +431    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158
```

2. site.log:

---

```
ERROR - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceTransportException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.Caller.ODataContextEngineServiceClient..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.ODataContextEngine..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider..cctor()
```

3. cd_client.log

---

```
2020-07-06 22:49:11 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceProvider..ctor] - Attempting to construct discovery-service provider.
2020-07-06 22:49:14 WARN [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceClient.CreateTokenProvider] - No token-servuce uri was available so unable to use authentication.
2020-07-06 22:49:14 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceProvider..ctor] - Finished constructing discovery-service provider.
2020-07-06 22:49:16 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Failed to load assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872'. Check the versions present match this assembly.
2020-07-06 22:49:16 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
           at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
           at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
           at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
           at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(IBuildManager buildManager, Predicate`1 predicate)
           at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(String cacheName, Predicate`1 predicate, IBuildManager buildManager)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache.EnsureInitialized(IBuildManager buildManager)
           at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypes()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.MapAttributeRoutes(RouteCollection routes, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Global.asax.cs:line 48
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Global.asax.cs:line 228
           at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
           at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
           at System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(HttpContext context, MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs, HttpSessionState session)
           at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireApplicationOnStart(HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalled(HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
           at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)
2020-07-06 22:49:16 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Failed to load assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4450e3c7f68bf872'. Check the versions present match this assembly.
2020-07-06 22:49:16 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve]
        Stack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
           at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Logger.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
           at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
           at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
           at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(IBuildManager buildManager, Predicate`1 predicate)
           at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(String cacheName, Predicate`1 predicate, IBuildManager buildManager)
           at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache.EnsureInitialized(IBuildManager buildManager)
           at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypes()
           at System.Web.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.MapAttributeRoutes(RouteCollection routes, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Global.asax.cs:line 48
           at Tmsc.Web.Site.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\soumava\work\code\tmsc web\Site\Global.asax.cs:line 228
           at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments).
```

4. discovery service log [cd_core.log]:

---

```
2020-05-20 00:21:29,217 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Read timed out
2020-05-20 00:21:29,236 ERROR ODataQueryProcessorImpl - Unexpected Exception when executing query.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:305)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.jpa.JPAODataDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPAODataDAO.java:74)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigDataSource.executeQueryListResult(TridionConfigDataSource.java:630)
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigDataSourceProvider$1.execute(TridionConfigDataSourceProvider.java:84)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataQueryProcessorImpl.query(ODataQueryProcessorImpl.java:94)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:38)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
```

Please help me to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Apparently, your Discovery Service gets a timeout while trying to read from its database.

Comment: @Rick: that is true. but that is only happening when try to run application from local machine. but from dev server its working correctly. and thats confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was found.
on deployer server TLS has been updated but on my local machine that ha snot been updated. that is why connection from local machine was not working but working from dev server.

post TLS has been updated issue has been resolved.